# Custom Chat Window Queue Position Conditional Message

Tags: visualforce, liveagent, queue

I'm using the liveAgent:clientChatQueuePosition tag in a customized chat window to display a visitors place in the queue. When an alert has been sent to the agent, however, the value is null. Does anyone know how to make this conditional so that if the value is null another message is displayed?

Here is the non-conditional code that I am currently using.

```
<table id="waitingMessage" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td>You are currently # <liveAgent:clientChatQueuePosition/> in line to chat with a Technical Information Scientist. </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Did liveAgent:clientChatQueuePosition work for you? I can't display either

Comment: Worked after changed the "Routing Type" from "Choice" to "Most Available"

Answer (score 1):

If all three of these conditions **aren’t** met, `liveAgent:clientChatQueuePosition` doesn't display a value.

- The button from which the chat was requested must have queuing enabled.
- All online agents (with the relevant skills, if applicable) must be at capacity, causing a queue to form.
- The chat must be in the queue and not yet assigned to an agent.

Comment: Yes, I'm clear on why it doesn't display a value. I'm looking for a way to utilize that as a condition to show a different message.

Comment: oh! Have you tried to assign it to a variable <apex:variable> and display the value only if the variable is not null ?

Comment: I don't seem to be able to get it to render with a value as a variable.  Error: Unknown property 'liveAgent:clientChatQueuePosition' referenced in TIS_Chat_Custom. 
           <apex:variable value="{!liveAgent:clientChatQueuePosition}" var="queuePosition" />

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

span.liveAgentQueuePosition:empty::before {
        content: '1';
    }